Es war zu leisten = you had to do it/it was doable?
Please look at the following article: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/asien/israel-gazastreifen-polio-100.html
What does "Vor dem Krieg war das zu leisten, es gab ein funktionierendes Gesundheitssystem." mean?
In particular, how am I to understand the zu leisten part? Google Translate suggests that "before the war, it [i.e. vaccinating children against Polio] was possible..." and it does seem to make sense, given the context. However, doesn't it actually mean, it had to be done before the war? Es war zu leisten, you had to achieve it, you had to do it?

The phrase itself can actually be read both ways. If "es war zu" is read as something like "it had to be done", it sounds quite formal, stiff and a bit outdated. You may find this meaning in administrative / bureaucratic texts, legalese and the like.

Es war zu klären, wer über die neuen Maßnahmen informiert werden musste.
It needed to be worked out, who had to be informed about the new arrangements.

The other meaning, something like "it was achievable", is much more common in every day speech.

Das Team sah sich vor einer schwierigen Aufgabe, aber es war zu schaffen.
The team was faced with a difficult task, but it could be done.

The only way to decide which meaning is intended in a specific case is from the context. In your quote, the situation before the war is compared to the situation now, saying that now it is unclear how the goal can be achieved amidst the ongoing fighting:

Laut Experten sollten alle Kinder im Gazastreifen unter zehn Jahren gegen Polio geimpft werden - etwa 650.000 Kinder. Vor dem Krieg war das zu leisten, es gab ein funktionierendes Gesundheitssystem. Wie jetzt, angesichts der anhaltenden Kämpfe, 1,3 Millionen Impfdosen verteilt werden sollen, ist unklar.

which could be translated to something like

According to experts, all children in Gaza younger than 10 years should be inocculated against polio - that's roughly 650.000 children. Before the war that was doable, there was a working public health system. How now, faced with the ongoing fights, 1.3 mio. doses of vaccine should be distributed, is not clear.

So the comparison is between that the task was achievable before the war, and probably isn't anymore now.

I means vaccinating all those people had been possible before the war.
Unfortunately there is no way to know which one it is other than how the particular verb in question interacts with the context usually. There is no logic in that, just experience.
Usually both variants make some sense but one more than the other.

Yes. The standalone "war/ist zu leisten" is ambiguous in general. In the context with a post-scriptum that gives a reason that lowers the hurdles (here: there was a working health care system),  the meaning is "could be /can be done".
